# Springs yet again, this time with a picture. Infinite displacement, makes no sense

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, oscillators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could this damped oscillator ever go to infinity? Or negative infinity for that matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20637/how-could-this-damped-oscillator-ever-go-to-infinity-or-negative-infinity-for-t)

Consider this

http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/1391/78679184.jpg!

Where I purposely drew the right arrow bigger than the left one. The arrow to the right is the drag force - resistive force and the arrow to the left is the spring force.

So writing out Newton's second Law I get

$F = ma = bv - kx$ where I am taking the right direction as the increasing value of $a$

In differential form, I get

$F = mx'' = bx' - kx$

Before I solve and show you the solution, my intuition tells me that it with a damping force that's much greater than the restoring force, the mass won't even return to the equilibrium point. Unfortunately my intuition proves me very wrong.

$ mx'' - bx' + kx = 0$

Now, let b = 10, k = 2, and m = 1, x(0) = 1 and x'(0) = 0

http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/4044/70539281.jpg!

Now this makes no sense to me. The mass was originally displaced to the right of the equilbrium point and was released. After being released the drag force should resist so much that the restoring force isn't enough to counter it so that it should not even reach the equilibrium point. Now I have a graph that says it will go down to negative infinity.

Why?

Also, what does negative infinity mean? Doesn't that mean the spring will break?